# Trying to implement a binary tree search

Tags: haskell

Im trying to implement a Binary Tree Search algorithm in haskell.

```
data BinTree k d = 
   Branch (BinTree k d) (BinTree k d) k d 
  | Leaf k d 
  | Empty
  deriving (Eq, Show)
```

is the data structure im using to capture my binary tree. The problem is I dont know what to return if we cant find the value. This is what I have so far for my search function :

```
lkp :: (Monad m, Ord k) => BinTree k d -> k -> m d
lkp (Leaf a b) x
  | a == x = return(b)
lkp (Branch lSub rSub a b) x
  | a < x = lkp rSub x
  | a > x = lkp lSub x
  | a == x = return(b)
```

I can see in the tests that the test expects a return value of [] back yet I cannot understand how we return this empty value. This is an example of one of those tests :

```
testCase "3 in Leaf 5 500 ([]))[1 mark]"
    (lkp (Leaf 5 500) 3 @?= [] )
```

Comment: If your `m` type variable was meant to be a [MonadPlus](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Alternative_and_MonadPlus) instead of just a Monad, you could then return `mzero` for an `Empty` tree and also when the key you want cannot be found. Both `Maybe` and [] are [instances of MonadPlus](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we miss a way to return a “zero” or “empty” value.

Fortunately, the Haskell base library (Prelude) offers the [MonadPlus](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:MonadPlus) class. MonadPlus is a specialized version of Monad, which augments the regular Monad interface with `mzero` and `mplus`, providing essentially a monoid-like structure. Theory [here on the Haskell Wiki](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Alternative_and_MonadPlus).

Using `MonadPlus`, the code for `lkp` can be written as follows:

```
import Control.Monad

data BinTree k d = 
       Branch (BinTree k d) (BinTree k d) k d 
    |  Leaf k d 
    |  Empty
  deriving (Eq, Show)

lkp :: (MonadPlus m, Ord k) => BinTree k d -> k -> m d
lkp (Branch lSub rSub a b) x
  | a < x      =  lkp rSub x
  | a > x      =  lkp lSub x
  | otherwise  =  return b
lkp (Leaf a b) x  =  if (a == x)  then  (return b)  else  mzero
lkp Empty      _  =  mzero
```

**Note:**: I am using the `otherwise` keyword instead of the equality test in order to silence a spurious “*non-exhaustive patterns*” warning.

**Testing under ghci:**

```
 λ> 
 λ> :load q65169028.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( q65169028.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> tr1 = Branch (Leaf 1 2) (Branch (Leaf 5 6) (Branch (Leaf 9 10) (Leaf 17 18) 13 14) 7 8) 3 4
 λ> 
 λ> (lkp tr1 7) :: [Int]
[8]
 λ> 
 λ> (lkp tr1 8) :: [Int]
[]
 λ> 
 λ> (lkp tr1 17) :: [Int]
[18]
 λ>
```

We want to force the interpreter to choose lists as our MonadPlus instance, hence the `:: [Int]` type signature at the end of each line.

If that sounds too cumbersome, it is always possible the specialize the `lkp` function further, like this:

```
llkp :: Ord k => BinTree k d -> k -> [d]
llkp tr x = lkp tr x
```